# Addressbook.app won't start

Tags: macos

On my mac the Addressbook application won't start anymore.

/Applications/Addressbook.App does still exist, but it seems very slim in the contents. The actual binary doesn't exist anymore in this app directory.

Surprisingly, when I open up the Applications directory in Finder, the name of the application is now 'Agenda'.

I've had this exact problem before, the remedy at that time was to get my friend (who also owns a mac) to zip the actual Addressbook application, and I simply overwrote my version.

This time my friend is not around. Although I'm not sure, but the actual files for Addressbook seem to be gone, I'd like to know if anyone knows how this can happen in the first place. Kinda creepy if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem by finding another copy of Addressbook.app, zipping it, and overwriting my own.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look and see if the binary is in the Address Book.app package:

```
$ ls -la /Applications/Address\ Book.app/Contents/MacOS/Address\ Book 
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  1191520 Jun 23 14:24 /Applications/Address Book.app/Contents/MacOS/Address Book
```

If it does, you can just run it by taking out the ls -la part:

```
$ /Applications/Address\ Book.app/Contents/MacOS/Address\ Book
```

Not sure why anything would be deleting the binary though.

Comment: The 'Contents/MacOS' directory doesn't exist at all here :(

I wouldn't know either what could possibly delete this.. I'm gonna go find a replacement again =) Thanks though